# Cannot convert value of type ... to expected. argument type CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: swiftui, annotations, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I'm trying to get a map view with annotations, and it seems like things have changed recently with iOS 17. I get an error with the below code in the No2 ADVANCED MAP section saying - *`Cannot convert value of type '[NationalParkLocation]' to expected argument type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'`*

I'm fairly new to SwiftUI and would appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {

    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = {
        var mapCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 6.600286, longitude: 16.4377599)

        var mapZoomLevel = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 70.0, longitudeDelta: 70.0)

        var mapRegion = MapCameraPosition.region(MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapCoordinates, span: mapZoomLevel))
        
        return mapRegion
    }()
    
    let locations: [NationalParkLocation] = Bundle.main.decode("locations.json")
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Map(position: $cameraPosition) {
            Annotation("Test", coordinate: locations) {
                Image(systemName: "mappin")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried this:

```
 Map(coordinateRegion: $cameraPosition, annotationItems: locations,
            annotationContent: { item in
            MapPin(coordinate: item.location, tint: .accent)
        })
```

But no luck. Plus, pretty sure this was deprecated.

I've updated the code now to this:

```
struct MapView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = {
        var mapCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 6.600286, longitude: 16.4377599)
        var mapZoomLevel = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 70.0, longitudeDelta: 70.0)
        var mapRegion = MapCameraPosition.region(MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapCoordinates, span: mapZoomLevel))
        
        return mapRegion
    }()
    
    let locations: [NationalParkLocation] = Bundle.main.decode("locations.json")
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(position: $cameraPosition) {
            ForEach(locations, id: \.id) { item in
                Marker(item.name, systemImage: "mappin.and.ellipse", coordinate: item.location)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working as is now. Thanks.

Comment: Please post well formatted code without syntax errors ("MARK...") in it. Correct and formatted code is so much easier to read and makes the question clearer.

Comment: And what is NationalParkLocation and what has it got to do with iOS 17?

Comment: NationalParkLocation is the name of the model that's grabbing data from a json file. It doesn't have anything to do with iOS 17 - I just didn't word my question well.

Comment: Let me try again: I have some location data that I have (from a json file) that I want to show with markers or annotation on a map. But the code I have there is throwing that Cannot convert value of type error. Apologies if I wasn't clear

Comment: Ugh, I figured it out. Thanks!